# Fourier serie find $c_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, solution-verification, fourier-series, fourier-restriction

We let $f\in$$PC_{2\pi}$ and $f$ be $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$, $x\in[-\pi,\pi$]. I have to find the Fourier serie for $f$.
I have found the Fourier coefficients:
$$c_0= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-|x|}dx=\frac{(-1+e^{\pi})e^{-\pi}}{\pi}$$ because 
$$\int_{}^{}e^{-|x|}dx = \begin{cases} 
      e^{x}, & x \leq 0\\
     -e^{-x}+2, & 0<x \\
   \end{cases}
$$
and I have found with Wolfram Alpha:
 $$c_n= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-|x|}e^{-ikx} dx=\frac{e^{\pi(-1-ik)}(e^{2i\pi k}(-1-ik)+2e^{\pi+I\pi k}+ik-1)}{2\pi(k^2+1)}$$.
I think the calculation for $c_0$ is okay, but how can I formally show the calculation $c_n$? I need some help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write the integral as follows:
$$ \int_{- \pi}^{0} e^{x-ikx} dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-x-ikx} dx$$
This way, you avoid the use if the absolute value. Now, simple calculations of the above integrals will give you (after multiplying by $\frac{1}{2 \pi} $) the result.